# Ubuntu 20.04.2 Bluetoothctl SCAN from bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, bluetooth

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
bluetoothctl Version 5.53

The problem I have is a bluetooth headset being unable to directly pair without errors when switching between Ubuntu/Windows on a dual boot machine (I believe due to the process which bluetooth issues/stores public keys)

I am trying to run a simple script to remove a specific bluetooth address (device), flush its information and re-pair.

I have tried various iterations of:

```
#!/bin/bash

#remove old connection 
echo -e 'power on\ndisconnect 88:88:E1:21:52:BE\nremove 88:88:E1:21:52:BE\nquit' | bluetoothctl

sudo systemctl restart bluetooth 

sleep 1
echo -e 'power on' | bluetoothctl
echo -e 'default-agent' | bluetoothctl
echo -e 'discoverable on\ndiscoverable-timeout 100\nscan on' | bluetoothctl
sleep 10
echo -e 'pairable on' | bluetoothctl

# Re-Add our device
echo -e 'trust 88:88:E1:21:52:BE\npair 88:88:E1:21:52:BE' | bluetoothctl
sleep 4
echo -e 'connect 88:88:E1:21:52:BE' | bluetoothctl
echo -e 'discoverable off' | bluetoothctl
echo -e 'quit' | bluetoothctl
```

Output as follows:

```
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
[bluetooth]# disconnect 88:88:E1:21:52:BE
Attempting to disconnect from 88:88:E1:21:52:BE
[bluetooth]# remove 88:88:E1:21:52:BE
[bluetooth]# quit
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# default-agent
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
[bluetooth]# discoverable-timeout 100
[bluetooth]# scan on
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# pairable on
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# trust 88:88:E1:21:52:BE
Device 88:88:E1:21:52:BE not available
[bluetooth]# pair 88:88:E1:21:52:BE
Device 88:88:E1:21:52:BE not available
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# connect 88:88:E1:21:52:BE
Device 88:88:E1:21:52:BE not available
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# discoverable off
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# quit
```

However while following on the bluetoothctl command output in a seperate window

```
[CHG] Controller C8:58:C0:C4:41:F8 Name: [ControllerID]
[CHG] Controller C8:58:C0:C4:41:F8 Alias: BlueZ 5.53
[CHG] Controller C8:58:C0:C4:41:F8 Alias: [ControllerID]
**[CHG] Controller C8:58:C0:C4:41:F8 Discovering: no**
[CHG] Controller C8:58:C0:C4:41:F8 Discoverable: yes
```

The Scan on command has not had the desired effect. The bluetooth controller is not discovering and discovers no devices ergo no connection to said devices can be made.

When moving directly into the bluetoothctl command line, the scan on command has the desired effect and the controller begins scanning. Why is the scan ON command from the ubuntu terminal/bash script not having the desired effect?

Comment: SO is for programming questions only, so OS support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). Please ask on [ubuntu.se] instead.

Comment: ` | bluetoothctl` you are calling so many bluetoothctl processes. Just call it _once_, not multiple times. Research shell redirections and `exec` file descriptor spawning with process substitution and research coproc in bash.

Comment: I have the same problem with bluetooth headset on dual boot Ubuntu 22.04LTS and Windows 10. Do you have any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it was ever intended for `bluetoothctl` to ever be used in that way.

BlueZ provide a DBus APIs that are documented at:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

As an example of what can be done with the API, here is an example in Python doing something similar to your script.

```py
from gi.repository import GLib
from pydbus import SystemBus
from pprint import pprint

SCAN_TIME = 15
DEVICE_INTERFACE = 'org.bluez.Device1'
adapter_path = '/org/bluez/hci0'
device_address = '88:88:E1:21:52:BE'
dev_path = f'{adapter_path}/dev_{device_address.replace(":", "_").upper()}'


remove_list = set()

def stop_scan():
    adapter.StopDiscovery()
    mainloop.quit()


def clean_device(rm_dev):
    try:
        adapter.RemoveDevice(rm_dev)
    except GLib.Error as err:
        pass

def on_iface_added(path, interfaces):
    if DEVICE_INTERFACE in interfaces:
        on_device_found(path, interfaces[DEVICE_INTERFACE])

def on_device_found(device_path, device_props):
    address = device_props.get('Address')
    if address == device_address:
        stop_scan()

def pair_device():
    dev = bus.get('org.bluez', dev_path)
    dev.Trusted = True
    dev.Pair()


bus = SystemBus()
adapter = bus.get('org.bluez', adapter_path)
mngr = bus.get('org.bluez', '/')
mngr.onInterfacesAdded = on_iface_added

clean_device(dev_path)

mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()

GLib.timeout_add_seconds(SCAN_TIME, stop_scan)
adapter.SetDiscoveryFilter({'DuplicateData': GLib.Variant.new_boolean(True)})
adapter.StartDiscovery()

mainloop.run()

pair_device()
```

Comment: The python script ran into an issue on the pair Command. A bit confusing as we seem to provide the object path for the bus.get()?
---    
File "bt_hs.py", line 55, in <module>
    pair_device()
  File "bt_hs.py", line 35, in pair_device
    dev = bus.get('org.bluez', dev_path)
  File "/home/l/Desktop/scripts/bt_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydbus/proxy.py", line 59, in get
    return CompositeInterface(introspection)(self, bus_name, object_path)
KeyError: 'object does not export any interfaces; you might need to pass object path as the 2nd argument for get()'

Comment: Will poke around that documentation, perhaps there are some helpful concepts I will become aware of. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I'm also getting that error. You ever found out how to fix that?;)